# jq - how to select lowest or highest (no keys, no values in json)?

Tags: json, max, jq

I have this json:

```
[
  [
    "0.99980000",
    "3813863.19000000"
  ],
  [
    "0.99970000",
    "3813412.11000000"
  ],
  [
    "0.99960000",
    "1188619.16000000"
  ],
  [
    "0.99950000",
    "1992659.70000000"
  ],
  [
    "0.99940000",
    "3258570.31000000"
  ]
]
```

I would like to select the "highest of first" values, being 0.99980000 - how do I go about it with jq?

I wouldn't like to use shell's tail/head for that (i.e. "jq -r '.[] | .[]' | head -1" would output 0.99980000 - but it doesn't look that great and will not even work if the json data is not sorted already, at least not without yet more shell commands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max_by`:

```
jq -r 'max_by(.[0] | tonumber) | .[0]' file.json
```

Comment: Unfortunately this expects json is numbers, however, jq treats quoted numbers as string. So, max_by would produce 2.0111 as a higher number than i.e. 111.0111. So we'd need something like: jq -r 'max_by(.[0]|tonumber) | .[0]' file.json